# Get current PDO driver from existing connection?

Tags: php, pdo

I have a class that accepts an existing `PDO` connection in the constructor:

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct(\PDO $conn = NULL) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

My question is: is there a way to determine what driver an existing `PDO` connection is currently using (preferably from the list [found here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php))?  I didn't see anything in the API documentation.

For the curious, I'd like to know which driver is being used because functionality in my class is database-specific, so I'd like a way to validate that a connection being passed to it is of the proper type.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use [`PDO::getAttribute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getattribute.php) with `PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME`:

```
$name = $conn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I believe this will work.  It doesn't appear that the values returned by this are those listed on the available drivers page, though (for example, I'm seeing the string `oci` returned for Oracle 10g, instead of the expected `PDO_OCI` as listed on that page).

Comment: @drrcknlsn, That's because the names listed on that page aren't the real names.  Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php to get the real names.

Answer (score 5):

Use `getAttribute()`:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getattribute.php

```
$pdo_object->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME);
```